# How can a NestJS app listen on the same port as a connected microservice?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm trying to understand how Nest microservices work.

Let's start with this example from the docs (https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application)

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
// microservice #1
const microserviceTcp = app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
  transport: Transport.TCP,
  options: {
    port: 3001,
  },
});
// microservice #2
const microserviceRedis = app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
  transport: Transport.REDIS,
  options: {
    url: 'redis://localhost:6379',
  },
});

await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync();
await app.listen(3001);
```

After going through the source (https://github.com/nestjs/nest) , I understand `connectMicroservice` creates a `net.Server` when using `TCP` and the server starts listening when `startAllMicroservicesAsync` is called.
But then `app.listen` should initialize the listening of the base Nest webserver.

Why doesn't that cause an error?

I checked what happens if I have two microservices connected on the port. It sure does throw an error. What am I missing here?

```
// CODE CAUSES ERROR AS EXPECTED

const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
// microservice #1
const microserviceTcp = app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
  transport: Transport.TCP,
  options: {
    port: 3001,
  },
});

// microservice #2  <--- THIS WILL CAUSE AN ERROR AS EXPECTED
const microserviceTcp = app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
  transport: Transport.TCP,
  options: {
    port: 3001,
  },
});

await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync();
await app.listen(3001);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case anyone is interested: it is because microservices and "classic" Nest apps register ports with different defaults. Using `lsof` to check the open TCP sockets it is immediately clear.

```
localhost:3000 (LISTEN). // microservice
*:3000 (LISTEN)          // http app
```

If I explicitly provide a `hostname` as `localhost` for `app.listen` in `main.ts`, HTTP app fails to start, as expected.