# NestJS Hybrid App - microservice & app port conflict - EADDRINUSE address already in use

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nestjs

I have a basic nest app with following code

```
async function bootstrap(port: number) {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
            port,
        },
    });
    await app.startAllMicroservices();
    app.enableCors();
    await app.listen(port, () => {
        logger.log(`HTTP Server listening at ${port}`);
    });
}

const port = +process.env?.PORT || 3001;
bootstrap(port);
```

This code throws error

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
```

I have basic understanding what is happening, I am using same port for microservice as well as `app.listen()`. Even though they are pointing to same port, This should work according to [nestjs doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application), and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64959626/550907

But I am getting the port already used error in my ubuntu server. When I run it in my local server it works. This makes me thinking perhaps something differently setup in the server.

Wondering if anyone else had the same issue and know how to solve this?

### My Observation:

When I comment out the line `await app.startAllMicroservices();` the application runs without an error.

So, Microservice starts on the given port

```
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [NestMicroservice] Nest microservice successfully started +8ms
```

after that when app tries to start it fails.

### Update 2

When I said it was running in my local machine. I didn't mention i was using docker in my local environment.

So, when I am running this in Docker (alpine node) it works, but not when running directly in ubuntu. I've tried it without docker in my local and it didn't work.

### Update

---

#### Is port 3000 free?

Yes `lsof -i tcp:3000` show empty output nothing running on the port.

#### Did you try changing port?

Yes, it didn't help

#### Did you try running it using npm instead of yarn?

Yes, it didn't help

#### Can you provide full console output?

Here is the console when I try to run in dev mode (yarn start creates same issue).

```
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] PrismaModule dependencies initialized +46ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ClientsModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] DiscoveryModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ScheduleModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] CacheModule dependencies initialized +15ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] CongestionsModule dependencies initialized +6ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [NestMicroservice] Nest microservice successfully started +8ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +48ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [RoutesResolver] CongestionsController {/congestions}: +0ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/congestions, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/congestions/clinic/:id, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +162ms
[Nest] 2544  - 05/24/2022, 2:07:03 AM   ERROR [NestApplication] Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000 +1ms
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1372:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1508:7)
    at ExpressAdapter.listen (/var/www/analyzer/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js:63:32)
    at /var/www/analyzer/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:167:30
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NestApplication.listen (/var/www/analyzer/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:156:16)
    at bootstrap (/var/www/analyzer/src/main.ts:20:2)
```

Comment: You probably have something on your ubuntu server that is already running and listening on port 3000. Try changing to a different port and see if it works

Comment: @JesseCarter that is not the case, i've updated my answer.

Comment: Related issue from github. As per the creator of nestJS this is to be expected https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/6851

Answer (score 1):

You have two apps listening on port 3000

- The microservice you connect to your app
- The app itself

You can use a different port for the microservice. As in the snippet below:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.TCP,
    options: {
      port: 8877
    }
  })
  
  app.startAllMicroservices();
  app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: Thanks. I just run into this problem when trying to add Kafka microservice to my Nest.JS app. Does it need the port to listen on its own, apart of connecting to Kafka server?

Answer (score -1):

To determine what is using that port:

```sh
lsof -i tcp:3000
```

Comment: that is not the case, i've updated my answer.